# System went to sleep during partition resize, ntfs format is now read as raw

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

I was switching linux distros and my boot partition needed to be 512mb or more and I had around 350mb. In the calamares installer I resized my data partition (800gb) a bit to accommodate the additional space requirement, and then when all looked good, I started the install and went for a walk. When I came back, I saw that my live-usb had gone to sleep and on coming back the install progress was frozen (at 2%) with 0 resource usage on htop.

I aborted the install, and on my dual boot windows, I checked the partition, and it read as raw. Tried ntfsfix to fix ntfs signature, but chkdsk still says `unable to determine volume version and state`. TestDisk says `mft is not self contained`.

Do note that the rest of the harddisk is functioning normally, and its just the partition i wanted to resize

MiniTool is able to list most of my data as recoverable, but i do not have additional space (900gb) to store this data. While about 80% of the data can be downloaded again, I would love to avoid losing the 20% (backups etc) and also avoid spending time and bandwith on the other half.

Is recovery still possible?

Comment: Just to clarify: By resize you probably mean you moved the start of the partition, right? // It might be best to buy a hard drive to back up that data now, before making further rescue attempts and/or modifications.

Comment: yes! exactly. I had hoped for an inplace recovery, I shall take a backup of whatever's necessary for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was unable to recover my partition as is. Used minitool to copy the files to an external hdd then moved them back after formatting the partition.